# Schedule the reboot of an AWS RDS (Postgres) instance at a certain time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way to schedule the reboot of an RDS instance to a certain time?

I know how to manually reboot it but I didn't see any UI or documentation on how to trigger a reboot at, for example, two minutes to midnight.

Comment: I don't think you can that precisely, but you can use [maintenance windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html#AdjustingTheMaintenanceWindow) to do it during a defined period.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

Use a combination of AWS services and a bit of scripting or coding.  First, notice that you can reboot an instance using the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/reboot-db-instance.html) or an SDK like [boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.reboot_db_instance). You can also [schedule a lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) to occur with [Cloudwatch Event Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html).  So you could write a lambda to reboot the instance and schedule it to happen at a given time using CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) enables you to explicitly schedule an RDS instance reboot.